# Find out SelectedIndex of editable ComboBox

Tags: c#, uwp, combobox

I have an editable `IsEditable = True` `ComboBox`. I need to perform a check when the user clicks a button.
I tried:

```
if (ComboBox.SelectedIndex == -1)
{
    // Warn the user
}
```

This works if the user doesn't select anything and just clicks the button, but if the user types in a custom value, the `SelectedIndex` remains `-1` which still triggers the warning.
Is there a way to change this?
Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using SelectedValue instead of SelectedIndex. Also what kind of data source is being put into this combobox? if (ComboBox.SelectedValue != null)

Comment: @mathis1337 Thanks! This works. I used SelectedValue, but didn't use != null, I was specifying a specific value. The data are just 2 choices and the user can type anything they want at runtime.

Comment: I put answer in. you wanna mark it as correct it will be appreciated.

Comment: @mathis1337 I don't see your answer posted.

Answer (score 1):

See answer posted by @mathis1337 in the comments.

> `if (ComboBox.SelectedValue != null)`

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ComboBox.TextSubmitted` event to know if the user has changed the field.

Check [How to make a ComboBox editable](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/combo-box#make-a-combo-box-editable) in Microsoft Docs for more detail.

Regards